# The call to LoadLibrary(...) failed, Win32 error 0n126 using windows debugger tool, windbg; w3wp.exe IIS Worker Process faulting

Tags: windows, debugging, iis, asp-classic, windbg

I'm using windbg to analyze a memory dump on a separate computer from where the dump file originated.  Inside the tool's commmand line, I typed in the following:

```
.loadby w3core w3core
```

Here's the error:

*The call to LoadLibrary(c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3core.dll) failed, Win32 error 0n126 "The specified module could not be found." Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access*

Update: The process which I create the dump file from is w3wp.exe.  I think that is for IIS.  It's the IIS Worker Process.  So, w3core.dll must be related to the IIS Worker Process.

Just to review my steps, I used the Debug Diagnostic Tool to monitor a crash of a particular process on Computer A.  (Computer A is running Windows Server 2003 Standard 32-bit, IIS 6; ASP.NET is NOT installed.)  This crash created a memory dump file.  I copied this dump file to Computer B, which has Debug Diagnostic Tool and windbg installed.  On Computer B, I added the dump file in the Advanced Analysis tab of the Debug Diagnostic Tool and clicked the "Start Analysis" button.  The analysis summary reported:

```
the module c:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\32.core.dll has caused an access violation     
exception(0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x53534553 on thread 4
```

I opened windbg and added the Symbol File Path

```
SRV*downstream_store*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

Then, I opened the dump file and typed in the above command and it spit out the aforementioned error.  I can assure that the file definitely exists.

What is the problem?  Is it because I'm debugging on Computer B, when, in fact, the dump file came from Computer A?  Beyond that, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Why can't I load this module?  Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: .load(by) loads windbg extensions; I don't know what w3core.dll is, but it seems a safe bet that it's not a windbg extension.  You probably want .reload instead.  That being said, it still won't work if the binaries are different.  Usually Microsoft has most of their binaries/symbols on their public server, but not always.  In that case you can copy the binaries to your local machine and point windbg to them.

Comment: Oh, interesting, it only loads windbg extensions. I was monitoring w3wp.exe, the IIS Worker Process. I created a memory dump file of the process.  .reload will load any DLL I wish?  Again, IIS does NOT have ASP.NET installed.  A third-party vendor program uses IIS for its web application; so, I don't know if this is a problem with their program or IIS 6.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: what happens when you open the dump using WinDbg when you are on the machine that created the crash dump, so this means installing WinDbg on machine A? does the error go away? You can also try entering `.symfix;.reload` at the command which should automatically setup the symbol path to the MS symbol server online but it is really nothing different to what you did with `SRV*....`

Answer (score 0):

Try loading w3core in depends (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) assuming you can find the dll (which if you can't would also explain it). If it is missing any dependent dlls it should show you there.